# changing the value of one object to true or false in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I'm trying change state of checkbox in redux. Everything is set up correctly except the last part. I try to send a "false" or "true" and the decide in action what to call but I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'payload' of undefined
```

This is my code

```
export function isChecked(isCheck) {

if(isCheck == false){
    return{
        type: "IS_TRUE",
        isCheck
    }
} else if (isCheck == true){
    return{
        type: "IS_FALSE",
        isCheck
    }
  }
}
```

If I put just else then it works fine but then second time around it doesn't change

Answer (score 3):

You are using redux in a wrong way, here is an example for checkbox:

```
// action

export const SET_CHECKBOX_VALUE = 'SET_CHECKBOX_VALUE ';
export function setChecked(checked) {
 return {
   type: SET_CHECKBOX_VALUE,
   checked
 }
}

// filter/Reducer

import { SET_CHECKBOX_VALUE } from '..your action file here';

const initialCheckboxState = { isChecked: false };

export default function checkBoxFilter(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CHECKBOX_VALUE :
      return { checked: action.checked}
    default:
      return initialCheckboxState;
  }
}

// component
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import * as checkBoxActions from '..your action file here';

class MyComponent extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    isChecked: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    setChecked: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={() => { this.props.setChecked(!this.props.isChecked) }>
        {this.props.isChecked}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    isChecked: state.checkBoxFilter.checked
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(checkBoxActions, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```